# log into a machine on same wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless

I have an Ubuntu server on a wireless network, supplied by Verizon, at home. How do I log into this server from my laptop which also has access to the same wireless network?
Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: If you're using SSH to connect, I don't believe an SSH server is installed by default, so you'll need to install OpenSSH server and start it before connecting. Here's a pretty simple howto if you do need to install it: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-ssh-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  From Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
ssh <host-username>@<hostname/ip-address>
```

If you don't know what the ip address of your server is, you can use nmap to find it (I am not an nmap expert, but something like `sudo nmap -sS 192.168.1.1-255` will usually do the trick.  Your server should be one of the hosts that nmap returns.

Comment: Good answer... `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-255` would be significantly faster, as it just does a simple ping test as opposed to a TCP SYN scan. You're just checking for a host to be up.

Comment: @stevieb that's a good point, I just pretty much default to a SYN scan, forgot pinging existed :P